# Numpy to list over 2nd axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, split

I would like to split a n-d numpy array based on a internal axis.

I have a array of shape `(6,150,29,29,29,1)`

I would like a list of arrays as - `[150 arrays of shape (6,29,29,29,1)]`

I have used the `list(a)`, but this has given me a list over axis 0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`arr.transpose(1,0,2,3,4,5)` or `np.swapaxes(arr,0,1)` put the 150 dimension first.  Then you can use `list`.

Or you could use a list comprehension

```
[a[:,i] for i in range(150)]
```

The transpose is somewhat better

```
In [28]: timeit list(arr.transpose(1,0,2,3,4,5))
47.7 µs ± 47.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [29]: timeit [arr[:,i] for i in range(150)]
88.7 µs ± 22.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [32]: timeit list(np.swapaxes(arr,0,1))
49.2 µs ± 51.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```